# MongoDB "TypeError: cb is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I call Activity interface to find all activites, I kept getting error of "TypeError: cb is not a function".

Development environment:

- Mongoose version: 5.8.11
- Node version: 12.13.1
- OS: MacOS Catalina v10.15

**Model.ts:**

```js
const Models: {[key: string]: SchemaDefinition} = {
  activity: {
    banner: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    customer: { type: String, default: null },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: String, default: null },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
  },
};

for (const model in Models) {
  if (model) {
    mongoose.model(model, new Schema(Models[model]));
  }
}

export function getModel (modelType: ModelType): Model<Document, {}> {
  return mongoose.model(modelType);
}
```

**Router.ts**

```js
const Activity = getModel('activity');

Router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { type } = req.query;
  const conditions =  type ? { type } : null;

  Activity.find(conditions, filter)
    .limit(20)
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(HttpStatus.ServerError)
          .json('Something went wrong when finding activities.');
      }
      if (doc) {
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK)
          .json({ data: doc });
      }
    });
});
```

The node app will crash only when I pass callback to `find()` or `enter()`.

**Errors are as follows:**

```
/Users/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1915
      return callback(err);
             ^
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4378:14
    at cb (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1915:14)
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:76:14
    at executeCallback (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:67:25)
    at handleCallback (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:129:55)
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/to_array.js:30:40
    at ClientSession.endSession (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:135:41)
    at Cursor.CoreCursor._endSession (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:399:15)
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/to_array.js:30:22
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:750:9
    at done (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:463:7)
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:547:11
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:76:14
    at executeCallback (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:67:25)
    at callbackWithRetry (/Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:135:14)
    at /Users/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:318:7
```

Comment: how does your query look like ?

Comment: make sure you are exporting router module in Router.ts